# NonlinearModelFit won't fit to gaussian data

Tags: plotting, fitting, nonlinear

The form I'm using should be correct because when I input my initial guesses it plots a shape similar to my data. When I use NonlinearModelFit, the fit is not correct at all and is almost flat, then curves at the end.

```
ClearAll[compton, \[Beta], l, e1, ec, e2, peakresponse, comptonresponse, response, e0]

listdata = 
  Import["B:\\PHY353L\\RelativisticDynamics\\NA22 day22.Spe", 
   "Table"];

databeta = Transpose[{Range[501], listdata[[2500 ;; 3000, 1]]}];
databetaplot = ListPlot[databeta]

peakresponse[\[Beta]_, e1_, e2_] := (Abs[\[Beta]*e2*\[Pi]])^(-1/2) * 
  Exp[(-(e1 - e2)^2/(2*\[Beta] * e2))]

nlmbeta = 
  NonlinearModelFit[databeta, 
   peakresponse[\[Beta], e1, e2], {{\[Beta], 80}, {e2, 100}}, e1, 
   MaxIterations -> Infinity];
nlmbeta
Print[nlmbeta["ParameterTable"]]
betaplot = Plot[nlmbeta[e1], {e1, 0, 500}, PlotRange -> All]
Show[databetaplot, betaplot]

Plot[peakresponse[130, e1, 100], {e1, 0, 500}]
```

[image: Plot of databeta]
Plot of my data
[image: Show[databetaplot, betaplot]]
Data + the bad fit
[image: peakresponse plot]
Form of the fit

In this google drive link are my notebook and data.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YVKG7ZhNp3jBhbGDLHdBu-mR7iq0Z91N

I am out of options to try.

Comment: Notice the y-axis on your data, compared to the plot of `peakresponse[130, e1, 100]`.

Answer (score 7):

Notice the y-axis range of the data (~20000), compared to the plot of the model (~0.005) . If you add an amplitude parameter to the model, it works much better.

```
peakresponse[a_, β_, e1_, e2_] := 
 a (Abs[β*e2*π])^(-1/2)*Exp[(-(e1 - e2)^2/(2*β*e2))]

nlmbeta = 
  NonlinearModelFit[databeta, peakresponse[a, β, e1, e2], 
   {{a, 3000000}, {β, 80}, {e2, 100}}, e1, 
   MaxIterations -> Infinity];

nlmbeta["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

```
betaplot = Plot[nlmbeta[e1], {e1, 0, 500}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[databetaplot, betaplot]
```

[image]